# How to split a list with multiple elements

Tags: python

How to split a list that has multiple elements and get a specific element.

Example:

```
a =[{Name:type=node_1,value=c2e8aa}]
```

Parse this and get 'node_1' in a variable.

```
a = node_1
```

Note:
value of a[0] is [{Name:type=node_1,value=c2e8aa}]

Comment: Since `a =[{Name:type=node_1,value=c2e8aa}]` yields a syntax error, what is your _actual_ code?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is that supposed to be a *string*? Then format it as string. But then why is `a[0]` supposedly the same as `a` itself? This makes little sense as is.